# Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: .local URIs not allowed:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, owin

I'm attempting to implement google authentication in my project, however, I keep getting the following message when I attempt to connect to the google provider.

```
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: .local URIs not allowed:
```

My project is local, and the uri is:

```
https://******.station.local/signin-google
```

Is there a work around I could use so I could test this feature?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Google OAuth, the redirect_url must be a valid url(or these two special `http://localhost` `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`). `.local` is not a valid domain name. What's the type of your app? If it's a installed app, you can use the special one.

Comment: So... how was this issue solved? I would like to use the return url from my .local domain.